# GIS web map, geospatial engineering advanced/mid/courses

Tags: web, gis, geospatial

I have been researching and googling looking for specialist courses where dig in deep within the field of Geographic Information System but mostly of them are introductions to and doesn't go in deep with more advanced topics.

All of them has very different reviews, modules and structure so I would like to know the experience and experience of person who are within the field and has taking part of some course who really recommend by their personal experience.

My company has offered me and some colleagues to enrol for a course to improve GIS skills and I would like to use it and take advantage of this opportunity.

I am working within a full-stack web development team, so I would like to boost my skills in this area, PostgreSQL, postgis and JavaScript. I have research and I would like something more advanced that the typical courses introduction to …

Which courses do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Penn State's online courses, especially the [Geospatial Programming and Web Map Development Certificate program](https://www.worldcampus.psu.edu/degrees-and-certificates/penn-state-online-geospatial-programming-and-web-map-development-certificate/overview). They also have a large number of their courses on-line as [open educational resources](https://open.ems.psu.edu/courses).

Disclaimer - I used to work at PennState.

Comment: That is the type of what I was looking for. Prices I don't know if my company will accept it but the course looks really interesting.

Comment: As I said you can wok through many of the course materials for free